# Protections for bidirectional motor controller circuit for DC brushed motor

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, pwm, dc-motor, motor-controller

I am designing an H-bridge based DC motor controller. It should be able to control 4 quadrant operation of a DC motor, therefore I am using four STB85NF55T4 MOSFETs and four IN58198RL Schottky diodes in parallel to my 24V supply. The Vcc in the picture is 15V for the driver IC from an [L78S](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/e9/be/53/a3/1f/6f/4f/75/CD00000449.pdf/files/CD00000449.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000449.pdf) voltage regulator.

Motor specification: MY1025 24V 14A, 250W 2750RPM, 0.8Nm La= 405µH, Ra=0.3899ohms.

I am controlling the MOSFET [STB85NF55T4](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/0b/fc/66/73/bd/1f/4a/de/CD00002747.pdf/files/CD00002747.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00002747.pdf) through an [IRS2011](https://rocelec.widen.net/view/pdf/3eur23zh08/INFN-S-A0001467921-1.pdf?t.download=true&u=5oefqw) half bridge driver. The driver will get 3.3V input as PWM from Raspberry Pi PICO.  Since I do not have a battery as power source, the current will come back to the power supply due to the energy stored in the inductor in the 2nd quadrant mode regenerative braking through D2 (diode in parallel to Q1) when Q3 is on. It will also happen on 4th qudrant operation reverse regenerative braking of the motor through D3 (diode in parallel to Q2) while Q4 operates. I hope I am correct so far.

What sort of protection do I need for my PCB and microcontroller?

Am I missing an overcurrent protection circuit?
Should I be worried ab out back EMF from the motor in freewheeling mode?
[image: Circuit without PICO]

I have Pico on another page. I don't know if that's necessary to discussion.

**Edited**
[image: M1 and M7 is for protection]
So, I did a simulation with different diodes and a popular circuit called Braking resistor. But of course sizing a braking resistor for pcb would be impossible. I wanted to add M7 to shutdown when M1 the chopper MOSFET goes on. That would stop huge current due to shortcircuit when my main H-bridge circuit switch is on. But, i am getting huge spikes of current at drain about 800A for 285ns, when i turn on the MOSFETS. Clearly it is not in the Safe operating area of my MOSFET. So, my circuit is not working.
Any mistakes, that you can see?

[image: Spikes at drain of MOSFET]

Comment: A 1A diode for a 14A motor? Its pretty obvious you have no overcurrent protection. Is it likely the motor may be stalled? If so, you might want to add it. The diodes should catch the freewheeling and clamp it to the rails. The 1A diodes might get a little stressed though.

Comment: Also make sure that the motor can't increase the voltage way over 15V when freewheeling. Because your voltage source most probably won't be able to sink curent.

Comment: @Kartman how about tvs diode like LDP01-56AY instead of those? Also do you have any suggestion circuit when it comes to overcurrent protection?

Comment: @kruemi How do i make sure that i can go up to 24v, since i want to run the motor fast. any literature on that?

Comment: @rafi oh sorry. I meant 24V. I've misread that... 24V should be ok. Just make sure that your motor does not raise Vcc above that when freewheeling (basically working as a generator) or make sure, that your design can handle that as well. It should not be a problem as long as there is no external thing increasing the rpm of the motor.